# Any performance gain when using Any etc on List

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any performance gain when using Any extension method than the old for loop way?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the "old for loop way"? Any works on enumerables, so not sure how for loop can be generally used. Perhaps I'm tired and missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no; the performance is likely to be *marginally* poorer.

In practice, the brevity and clarity of this approach is going to have maintenance benefits over a loop and will be less prone to bugs.

Think of it this way: if you write 50 loops and forget to short-circuit evaluation in one of them, you'd have been better off using `.Any` in all 50.

Comment: Just some additional thought, **If used correctly**, Parallel LINQ may offer some performance advantages as well. I am not advocating throwing `AsParallel` everywhere. But it's another option to consider.

Answer (score 0):

For indexed collections you could the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < col.Length;i++)
{
  if (predicate(col[i]))
    return true;
}
return false;
```

but for non-indexed `IEnumerable<T>`, this is not possible, as it doesn't supply an indexer. This would be the implementation in the framework (via reflection):

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    }
    foreach (TSource local in source)
    {
        if (predicate.Invoke(local))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As it iterates over all elements of the `IEnumerable<T>`, there is no performance gain to be had. However, any "optimization" in this direction would fall under premature optimization, if there is a performance problem, it is more likely to be fixed in your algorithm than in this function.

Comment: Using `.Any()` will be calling a function pointer for each item, and this incurs a performance penalty.  The question is not which approach will be faster (an inline `foreach` will certainly be faster due to the lack of a function pointer call and the possibility of compiler optimizations not otherwise possible with a delegate) -- the question is *how much* faster `foreach` would be.